# Is it possible to control the weather?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft, weather is really rare and I like having it. I'd especially like to see thunderstorms. What I was wondering is if there was a way to control or influence the weather? I'm guessing no, but there's no harm in asking... right? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access a console in either mode to force weather changes unfortunately. Apparently a seed called "takefive" is 100% winter [According to this forum post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/632873-minecraft-xbox-360-edition/65746894/738442681)

Comment: "100% winter" will only give you lots of snow already on the ground, not increase the frequency of it falling from the sky via weather.

Comment: My logic process for that is if it is already on the ground then it would require more to be falling, but that may be flawed and as with everything from the internet is worth a grain of salt. If I need to be directly answering the question then I guess I should just tell them NO. Not give them options.

Comment: Saying "no," *then* offering alternative options or compromises is actually a pretty good way of answering questions like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can control to a certain degree if it's your server of you have admin rights.

Try the following commands:

```
/weather sun 
/weather rain
/weather thunder
/toggledownfall
```

With these I usually control the weather on my server.

Comment: Are you sure this works in the console edition of minecraft?